# Binding image source with file input using knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have a image control and file input control,

```
   <img data-bind="attr:{src:Picture}">
     <span><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></span><input type="file" name="Picturefile" data-bind="value: Picture"></label>
 <div class="btn btn-group">
            <button type="submit" value="save" data-bind="click: editClient" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-ok"></i>Save!</button>
            <a href="/admin/client" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>Back to list</a>
        </div>
```

On editing a entity, I want to bind the current picture with image control, also the user can edit and select a new picture using file control,

Here is my javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var ClientObject = {
            Name: "",
            Picture: ""

        }
        function Client(data) {
            var self = this;
            this.editClient = function () {
                var datatoPost = ko.mapping.toJS(self);
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    method: 'post',
                    type: 'application/json',
                    url: '/api/my/client/',
                    data: datatoPost,
                    success: function (d) {
                        toastr.info("Saved");
                    }
                })
            }
            console.log('mapping to js',data);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ClientObject, self);
        }

        var loadData = function (id) {
            var _url = '/api/v2/my/client';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: _url + '/' + id,
                success: function (d) {
                    if (!!d.error) { console.log(d.message); }
                    else {
                        var model = new Client(d);
                        ko.applyBindings(model, document.getElementById("clientCreate"));
                        console.log(model);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        loadData(@ViewBag.Id);
    });
</script>
```

So on loading I get the following error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

New to knockout !!

Comment: This error is happening because you can't update the value of a file input field as that would be a security issue. What data is coming back from the ajax call?

Comment: I get the model object from ajax call, for picture, complete path of picture (string value).

Comment: You can't update the file input field with the path as that would be a security issue. You could maybe instead just add the path as text to the page

Comment: Okay, but I want to then bind the image control when a different file is choosen , how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I had to create a custom binding to do it. I haven't done any cross browser testing but I think it will work on all current browsers.

```
<input type="file" data-bind="fileSrc: src" id="file"/>
<img data-bind="attr:{src:src}"/>

$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.src = ko.observable();
};

ko.bindingHandlers.fileSrc = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                value(e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
        });
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vfKZ/1/